# Angular Material Dropdown inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angular, less, angular-material2, angular-material-5

I have an Angular 5 app that must use Angular Material's `mat-select` inside a Bootstrap modal. The issue is that the dropdown options appear behind the modal. My code looks like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="mdb-form-field form-adjustments">
    <mat-select placeholder="What fruit are you looking for?" [formControl]="fruitType" [(ngModel)]="defaultFruitType">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let fruitType of fruitTypes" [value]="fruitType">{{ fruitType }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I know I should be using the `z-index` to bring Angular Material's selection options to the front. But the question is on what class? I tried applying it to multiple classes from Angular Material, but to no avail. All of the following have failed:

```
body div.cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 99999;
}

/deep/ .cdk-overlay-pane {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}

/deep/ .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper, .cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}

.mat-select-menu-container {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}

.mat-dialog-container {
  z-index: 99999;
}

/deep/ .mat-select-panel {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}

/deep/ .mat-primary {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

Does anyone know on which class of Angular Material I must apply the `z-index` to bring the select options to the fore of the modal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I experienced the same issue with Angular Material 6/Bootstrap 4. I resolved the issue with the following style in styles.scss file -

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
     z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: I had to add `!important` to it but this worked. I wasted hours searching for a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I experimented with many hack-aways but only thisone worked for me:

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for anyone still having trouble with this in 2022, try this:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Posted full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73182885/17286186