# Angular Material Dropdown inside md Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, mdbootstrap

I have tried this -> [Angular Material Dropdown inside Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851616/angular-material-dropdown-inside-bootstrap-modal)
but its not working for me.
I am using Angular select inside the md bootstrap.
The issue is that the dropdown options appear behind the modal. My code looks like this:

```
<button type="button" mat-button data-toggle="modal" style="background: #dc6254 !important;" style="margin-top: -1px;"  data-target="#basicExampleModal">
      Select
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicExampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Fill the following</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <mat-form-field> 
            <mat-select name="status" ngModel  placeholder="Status">
              <mat-option value="Accepted">
                Accepted
              </mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Rejected">
                Rejected
              </mat-option>
              <mat-option value="hold">
                Hold
              </mat-option>
               <mat-option value="West">
                In Process
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          </div>



    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" mat-button data-dismiss="modal" style="outline:none;">Close</button>
      <button type="button " mat-button style="outline:none;" >Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your code in snippet

Comment: Try z-index of css. Might be that helps you

Comment: tried z-index every where

Comment: In case you are still wondering, I found that this worked for me instead: .cdk-overlay-container{
  z-index:2000;
}

Comment: I just used Angular material dialog instead of bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851616/angular-material-dropdown-inside-bootstrap-modal) but doesn't worked.
I tried adding these lines in **styles.css** and it worked for me.

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
}

.cdk-overlay-container { z-index:2000; }
```