# Mat select options showing behind the Dialog

Tags: autocomplete, angular6

I am including form inputs, mat select with options and autocomplete field with options too into a matDialog box.
The problem is that the options are showing behind the Dialog. I’ve already came across those solutions [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352238/why-mat-select-not-working-inside-the-modal-onclick-it-shows-options-behind-th) but did'nt solve this problem.
here is my code:

```js
<mat-form-field class="wrapField">
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="selectChange($event)" formControlName="product" placeholder="Alle Produkte">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" value="{{product.id}}">{{product.nummer}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="wrapTime">
  <input matInput placeholder="Startzeit" [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="startTime" required>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

et here is the style.css file:

```css
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper, .cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix that ?

Answer (score 14):

I too had the same issue. As you have found out, this bug is due to the conflicts of z-indices. So I put the following CSS in my `global.css` which solved the issue:

```
.cdk-overlay-container, .cdk-overlay-pane {
     z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Comment: can i specific this inside class like .homepage .cdk-overlay-container, .cdk-overlay-pane ?

Comment: I had the same issue and I added the code you wrote into my styles.scss and it worked like a charm. thanks a lot, Steffi.

Comment: Glad to help @Andrecon :)

Comment: Perfectly working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and none of the answers (also from different questions) worked for me.

The only answer that was efficient is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59520876/9158986) where @Zahema is saying:

> Not recommeding the z-index: 99999 !important; AT ALL. It's a very
> exteme soultion that should be used only as a last resort.
>
> In my case it was that the modal was opened in a non-standard way. If
> you open it using MatDialog service you shouldn't find any issues. If
> there is then your code is what introduced them, try not to hack your
> way into a fix.

This solution worked perfectly for me.