# Display mat-select in front of a dialog embedded within a modal in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-material

It looks as if mat-selects disappearing behind modals and behind dialogues are both problems that have been addressed many times on SO with

`.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper, .cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 9999!important;
}`

in the global styles.scss.

I have implemented this suggestion successfully in my application in the case where I have a mat-select in a modal:
[image]

However, when I try to have a mat-select in a dialog *within* a modal, the mat-select menu appears above the modal but behind the dialog:

[image]

Any suggestions very welcome and much appreciated. I'll try to create a minimal reproducible example if people think it's warranted, but if there's an easy solution I'm not aware of, I'd like to try that before implementing a complex app structure on stackblitz...

Comment: Please reproduce this issue in stackblitz

Comment: This issue may have already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53062626/11854340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually that css rule that *causes* the issue, if you want to continue to use that css, try adding `.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box` to the css rule:

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper, 
.cdk-overlay-container, 
.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box {
    z-index: 9999!important;
}
```

Comment: That did it. How did you know this?

Comment: We use material at my work, and have had similar issues with the indexing of elements. I just followed the html structure down to the element that contains the select list itself and make sure the z-index matches it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the z-index of the dailog box and reduce it below at the level from of the mat select this way your mat-select will be displayed on the top of the dialog box